# how to render formula's with MathQuill

Tags: javascript, formula, mathquill

I'm trying to render formulas with MathQuill, without much succes. I've tried different ways.

For example, if I do

```
$('#formula').mathquill('latex', 'a_n x^n');
```

it renders the formula, except that it starts with `$$`

Here is a simple [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3n5nydsc/3/)

Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of
`.prepend('<span class="selectable">$'+root.latex()+'$</span>');`
used in mathquill.js [line no. 1338- function: createRoot]

It does this for non-editable textboxes.(Doesn't get why?)
But to avoid this you can make text area editable and then revert it as:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3n5nydsc/4/)

Please suggest if found any better way.